# Execute SQL query c#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

this is the code :

```
con.SqlQuery(" SELECT TOP 1000 [Name],[CompanyName],[Version] FROM[MicroinvestDatabasesCatalog].[dbo].[MicroinvestDatabases] ORDER BY NAME");
                con.NonQueryEx();
```

and the class for connection and query:

```
  public SqlConnection conn;
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlDataAdapter da;
        public DataTable dt;
        public DataSet ds;

        public void SqlDbConnect()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection($"Data Source={server};User ID={user};Password={password};");
            conn.Open();

        }

        public void SqlQuery(string queryText)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, conn);
        }

        public DataTable QueryEx()
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        public void NonQueryEx()
        {

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

but have problem with `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
Can someone help with this problem?
Try different query but is still same...

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: `have problem with cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` What problem did you have?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() is for Updates, deletes or Inserts. Not for a SELECT as in your example.

Comment: Please use ExecuteReader() here. ExecuteNonQuery() is meant for insertion, deletion or updation of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your class `SqlDbConnect`. You have a field `public SqlConnection conn` but in the constructor you create a new variable of type `SqlConnection` and open that instead. In the constructor you need to use the classes field:

```
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    public SqlDataAdapter da;
    public DataTable dt;
    public DataSet ds;

    public void SqlDbConnect()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection($"Data Source={server};User ID={user};Password={password};");
        conn.Open();
    }

    public void SqlQuery(string queryText)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, conn);
    }

    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    public void NonQueryEx()
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Additionally, if you want to select data you can't use `ExecuteNonQuery`. Instead better use the method `QueryEx()` which returns you a `DataTable`:

```
con.SqlQuery("SELECT TOP 1000 [Name],[CompanyName],[Version] FROM[MicroinvestDatabasesCatalog].[dbo].[MicroinvestDatabases] ORDER BY NAME");
DataTable dt = con.QueryEx();
```

Comment: Can u show me with code? Sorry, but I'm new and I still learn.

Comment: No Problem. Everybody has to start somewhere! I've updated my answer. The first code sample is a corrected version of the class `SqlDbConnect` and the second uses your query and stores the result in a `DataTable`.

Comment: I'm rally thankful but still have error. Maybe i forgot this line from code in MainWindows.xaml.cs :
private Connection con;

Comment: Could you show me the complete code of MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Comment: Change it to `private SqlDbConnect con = new SqlDbConnect();`